# Magento query from multi-sites

Tags: magento

I have multi-sites on magento and also have a simple script to load attributes. My problem is how to get which store to select as default when i run the script. I tried something like this but gives me no results. Any help?

```
Mage::app('store', 'website');
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the addStoreFilter.  This is the code I use to do something similar:

```
$storeID = '##'; // replace ## with the numerical id of the store (i.e. 1, 2, 20, 100, etc.)

Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeID); 

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeID)->getCollection();
$products->addStoreFilter($storeID);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//enabled
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in'=>array(2,3,4)));//catalog, search
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$prodIds=$products->getAllIds();
```

Comment: still gets all products from all sites

Comment: I just tested the code again by itself and it works for me.  If you are using the correct store view number for the filter, then you should only see the products assigned to that store.  If you're using a non-existant number, then the results would be blank.  Are normal pages on the sites are filtered correctly?

Comment: Thanks for it. It worked for the auxiliary site, but the main site brings up all products. Thanks.